# How to access .pem file from amazon emr

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Im new to amazon EMR and i want to use .pem file in EMR.
.pem file is in my local folder. When i create same file with pem file contents in EMR instance its not working.
it would be really help if anyone can provide steps to copy file to EMR from local machine or access file from S3.

thhanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish? What did you try, and what is the error or situation that results?

Answer (score 1):

create a bootstrap script to copy .pem file to EMR boxes

use below command in bootstrap script to download file to any loction of EMR ( I am downloading file to /mnt/

```
#!/bin/bash
hadoop fs -copyToLocal s3:n://mybucket/myfolder/my.pem /mnt/my.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to copy the keypair.pem into the master node then ssh core nodes. Then, you can copy the file from your computer using winscp or by running the command

```
sftp -i key.pem hadoop@master 
put keypair.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to transfer the .pem file to one of the EMR instances. So, you can use the winscp application to do such operation. If you are not familiar with such application, have a look on this tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html). Let me know if you need any help..